# How to apply CSS from parent component?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, emotion

There is a React component using Emotion called OtherComponent:

```
OtherComponent:
...
return <div css={otherComponentStyles}>
     <div className='something'>
     </div>
</div>
```

And another component called MainComponent that uses OtherComponent:

```
MainComponent:
...
return <OtherComponent css={mainComponentStyles} ... />
```

What happens in this situation is that OtherComponent properly uses otherComponentStyles. But it ignores mainComponentStyles.

But what I would like to do is to apply style to OtherComponent from the level of MainComponent.
I know i can wrap OtherComponent into a div, ad set css=... to the div. But it is a nasty fix of the problem.

Hence the question: how to apply CSS with Emotion from parent component aka MainComponent?

Comment: `css` attribute in div. is it a typo in other component `<div css={otherComponentStyles}>...`

Comment: @nilesh Patel there should be a component instead of div. Will change it later. Anyways the question is still valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not applying those styles to any html tag, it's not `<OtherComponent>` which is rendering, it's the `<div>` which is rendering to the page, so you must apply styles to a valid html tag.

Comment: Could you clarify?